# PHP with PDO and SQLS using prepared statments

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, prepared-statement

I have recently started to learn php and currently i am working on a project in which i have to send and get information to a MSSQLS Database. I have heard PDO is the right way, so  i managed to make the following code reading some tutorial:

```
 $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; // The hashed password.

$connection = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='. HOST .';Database=' . DATABASE, USER, PASSWORD);
$connection->query("use sub_secure_login");

$query = 'SELECT ID, username, password FROM members WHERE email = ?';

                // Prepare the query
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
                // Set the arguments array
                $array = array($email);
                // Execute the prepared query with the specified params
                $stmt->execute($array);

                $fetch = $stmt->fetch();

                error_log('id: ' . $fetch['ID']);
                error_log(' username: ' . $fetch['username']);
                error_log(' password: ' . $fetch['password']);
```

SQL table name: members
with the following columns: ID - username - password

Basically, `$email = $_POST['email']` is submited by a login form.

I dont know what is wrong in my code. Not sure if it is the query that is wrong, or something else. No error is shown in php_error_log and the loggs that i made are returning nothing but id, username, password.

Any help would be apreciated, and if possible, more information about using PDO, prepared statments with MSSQLS

Comment: Done any basic debugging? Checked `var_dump($_POST)`? Checked the return values from all of your db calls for boolean false (aka failure)?

Comment: i have solved the issue. I am sorry, these are those things that we spend hours trying to find the mistake and at the end it is a simple line change or bad configuration. The problem was that the user assigned to that database didnt have permissions. Since i have waste your time and the question is solved, could you please point me out some usefull guides/tutorial about checking var_dump($_POST) and and the return values from all of your db calls. I have no idea how to do so. Im sorry for the mistake and thank you anyway for your help!